# What ever happened to "fink"?

Tags: expressions, american-english, slang

(Child of the 70's here...) While in conversation with a millenial yesterday, I used the word ***"fink"*** to describe a low, sneaky, two-faced *um*, fink. She'd never heard the word. *"Ratfink"?* Nope. *"The Wizard of Id...'The king is a fink'?"* Nope.

Now, I know what happened to ***"gyp"***, (which was as commonplace as yo-yo's and bubble gum, in my day) but, why abandon a perfectly innocent word like "fink"?

I tried the N-gram thing - didn't get far. I found a blurb on this site by FumbleFingers (hoping you can lend a hand here, FF)

I recently relocated, so this may just be a regional anomaly... But, I am curious... Has **"fink"** disappeared from the AmE lexicon?

Comment: For a moment there I thought you were talking about cockney pronunciation of "think". It's been years and years since I hear or read the AmEng slang meaning of "fink".

Comment: This is the first time I've ever heard of the word. (Or at least that I can recall. If I have, it hasn't been memorable.)

Comment: It has gone the way of a lot of slang. It's quite dated. Like mid-sixties dated. And don't forget its companion, the rat: rat fink. :) If you don't know it, you are either too young or not an AmE speaker. From an even earlier era: swell for cool. I think that topped off in the fifties.

Comment: [batfink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batfink)

Comment: So far as I know the king is still a fink.  (We won't get started on the president.)

Comment: Just wanted to mention that the surname "Fink" is so common that it's difficult getting "clean" Ngram searches.  Even "a fink" and "the fink" searches are polluted by the surname.  ("Rat fink", however, appears to make it through clean.)  A peak in the use of "fink" ca 1970 appears to be due to the works of Max Fink, psychiatrist.

Comment: It also should be noted that "fink" has a meaning distinct from "stinker", "SOB", et al, in that (in one sense) it implies someone who, eg, writes anonymous ob-ed pieces in the New York Times.  (Ie, a "snitch" or "informer".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Phink* is a jocular misspelling of *fink*, **which in US slang of the 50s and 60s** signified generally a despicable person and specifically a traitor or sneak, someone who betrays his criminal confederates to the police.
>
> A common intensive form was **rat fink**,… [@StoneyB](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/238232/44619)

[World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-fin1.htm) tells us that *fink* has three different meanings

> The first one recorded is of an unpleasant or contemptible person (sometimes in the extended form *ratfink*), but the more common one today is that of someone who informs on people to the authorities. There’s also a third sense, now dated, of a strike breaker.

Michael Quinion, the author, suggests that the term is derived from 19th century German slang, meaning "finch", used to describe undergraduates who were not members of a college fraternity. The meaning of *fink* then extended to “not one of us”.

Today in the 21st century, you just don't hear *[fink](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/fink)* or *[stinker](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/stinker)* being used in American movies or in cable TV shows, let alone by rap or hip-hop artists.

I suspect that the younger generations replaced the euphemism "fink" with its more direct and taboo counterparts,  *[motherfucker](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/motherfucker)*, *son of a bitch*, and similar ilk. Less derogatory and offensive terms would be: *scoundrel, villain, rogue, rascal, brute, animal, weasel, snake, monster, ogre, wretch, devil, good-for-nothing, reprobate, wrongdoer, evil-doer* (courtesy of *Oxford Dictionaries*). Interestingly, the same synonyms are suggested for both *fink* and *motherfucker*.

The term "fink" sounds twee and almost charming in comparison, a suitable utterance for a child but much less so for an adult. In fact, *[Batfink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batfink)* was a popular children's cartoon character, on both sides of the Atlantic, the TV cartoon was produced  from April 1966 to October 1967 and enjoyed a cult following when it was repeated during the 1970s and '80s.

The American English corpus, via [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20fink%2Ca%20stinker%2Cson%20of%20a%20bitch%2Ca%20motherfucker%2C%20a%20bastard&year_start=1930&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20fink%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20stinker%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cson%20of%20a%20bitch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20motherfucker%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20bastard%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ca%20fink%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20stinker%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cson%20of%20a%20bitch%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20motherfucker%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20bastard%3B%2Cc1), seems to concur that "fink" lost its derogatory appeal: a fink (blue), a stinker (red), son of a bitch (green), a motherfucker (yellow), a bastard (dark blue). The noun  form *fink* is way at the bottom, followed closely by *stinker*, and surprisingly, *motherfucker*.

[image]

If we focus our attention on the last three terms, and add the verb "is", i.e. *is a fink*, [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20a%20fink%2Cis%20a%20stinker%2Cis%20a%20motherfucker&year_start=1920&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20fink%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20stinker%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20motherfucker%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20fink%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20stinker%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20motherfucker%3B%2Cc1) should avoid those instances where the author's name, A. Fink, is cited. The expression “is a stinker” seems to have peaked in the 1950s while that of “is a fink” in the early 1970s. Both terms were surpassed in frequency by the infinitely more offensive insult, *motherfucker*, around 1985. The same time that coincided with the Generation X's coming of age.

[image]

---

<sub>Credit is due to the following users whose comments helped improve the answer: [@Lambie](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/463605/what-ever-happened-to-fink#comment1118894_463605), [@Hot Licks](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/463605/what-ever-happened-to-fink#comment1118984_463605), [@Mitch](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/463605/what-ever-happened-to-fink#comment1118996_463625), and [@user3293056](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/463605/what-ever-happened-to-fink#comment1118926_463605)</sub>

Comment: @Mari-LouA You may want to add [a graph that shows the changes in fink](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+fink%2Ca+stinker%2Ca+motherfucker&year_start=1930&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=), since the very taboo (and exactly synonymous) 'mother fucker' washes it out. As an AmE speaker, 'fink' is a word I recognize from early 80's Mad Magazine, one of those tepid euphemisms for I don't know what. And the graph shows it had a peak in the early 70's and has been trailing off ever since, directly answering the OP. And there's the Cohn bros movie 'Barton Fink' from the 90's

Comment: Remember to stay respectful and kind. Best to avoid sarcasm, jokes, subtle (or not-so-subtle) putdowns or unfriendly language, bigotry, or harassment. If a situation makes it hard to act kindly, stop posting. Instead, flag harmful behavior to alert moderators. More information: [Expected Behavior](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), [Code of Conduct](https://english.stackexchange.com/conduct).

Answer (score 2):

Usage of "**fink**" from an AmE perspective: it is still used, especially  in political and current events as evidenced by:

> Thus, the exam rooms of Old Nassau are some of the few places where it
>   is not just appropriate but necessary for a gentleman to **fink** on his
>   friends. *Slate* Aug 26, 2014

and

> That takes **finking** to a whole new level. *New York Times Apr 16, 2018*

and

> The president—that **fink**!—was trying to grab “every piece of credit.”
>   *Slate '12*

and

> Now I'm beginning to wonder if we are all becoming mesmerized by these
>   sly, furry **finks** and if they are mounting a bid for world supremacy.
>   *Guardian 2014*

and

> Everybody is -- everybody is **finking** on each other. *Fox News*, "Democrats' new rallying cry: 'Abolish ICE'," 30 June 2018

and finally from the late and great William Safire - NY Times '87:  [On Language; Goons and Ginks and Company **Finks**](https://www.nytimes.com/1987/11/01/magazine/on-language-goons-and-ginks-and-company-finks.html)

Comment: I like this answer, but that first quote isn't really evidence of modern usage, given that it's embedded in a quote from 1965.

Comment: @J.R. edited that one out and replaced with a 2014 excerpt.  Looking for  a couple more.

Comment: I don't know that it needed to be removed. I thought it made a nice start.